# Powershell: JSON to Excel

Tags: json, excel, powershell

I have had a problem for days and am now reporting here. I want to export several JSON files to an Excel spreadsheet. The JSON keys should form the headers and the values should be listed under the headers. Unfortunately, I have zero understanding of Powershell and can't get any further with the help of other threads, as I also don't understand why something works or doesn't work the way it does.

The json files look something like this

```
{"dataCollection": [
  {
    "objectID": 000001,
    "randomID": 123,
    "desc": "The sky is blue",
    "startTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.510",
    "endTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.511",
    "caseOne": true,
    "caseTwo": false,
    "caseThree": null
  },
  {
    "objectID": 333222,
    "randomID": 456,
    "desc": "example",
    "startTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.510",
    "endTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.511",
    "caseOne": false,
    "caseTwo": true,
    "caseThree": null
  },
  {
    "objectID": 111111,
    "randomID": 789,
    "desc": "Mo-Fr 60% 20-24",
    "startTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.510",
    "endTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.511",
    "caseOne": false,
    "caseTwo": false,
    "caseThree": null
  }
]}
```

My current code looks like this

```
$contentJson = Get-Content -Raw -Path $jsonInput | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj_list = $contentJson | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}}
$obj_list | Export-Csv $csvOutput -NoType -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding Unicode
(Get-Content -Path $csvOutput -Raw).replace('"','') | Set-Content -Path $csvOutput
```

This does give me a CSV with the information from the json, however it is transferred cell by cell and I have no idea how to create headers. Further this works at all only, as soon as I remove in the first line of the JSON (in this case {"DataCollection":), otherwise in the Excel table only the following is written: @{ttDebugTage=System.Object[]}

My goal is something looking like this:
[Excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etaP3.png)

This is the first time I'm working with Powershell and unfortunately I'm completely lacking in understanding, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The Json example is not valid (please try to create a [mcve] [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75080519/edit)) Anyways, to convert something like that to a csv file, you could just do: `($contentJson |ConvertFrom-Json).<the complete path to>.DataCollection |Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput`

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, the JSON files were only forwarded to me and I believe originate as an export from another program. The syntax corresponds 1:1 to the example I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
################## PFADE ###################
$jsonDirectory = 'DIR\TO\JSON\FILES'
$csvFile = 'DIR\TO\OUTPUT\FILE.CSV'
################ Variablen #################
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
############################################

#ALLE JSON FILES
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonDirectory -Filter *.json

#FILTER
$unwantedKeys = @("Example1", "Example2", "Example3")

#ARRAY ZWISCHENSPEICHER
$jsonData = @()

foreach ($jsonFile in $jsonFiles) {
    #Lädt JSON File
    $json = Get-Content $jsonFile.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json
    $firstKey = ($json.PSObject.Properties.Name)

    #Filter
    $json = $json.$firstKey | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty $unwantedKeys

    #Content ins Array
    $jsonData += $json
}

#Erstellt CSV und Importiert JSON Content
$jsonData | Export-Csv $csvFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding Unicode

#Anpassen von Spaltenbreite auf Valuelänge
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFile)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$range = $worksheet.UsedRange
$range.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$excel.Visible = $True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$contentJson = @'
{"dataCollection": [
  {
    "objectID": 000001,
    "randomID": 123,
    "desc": "The sky is blue",
    "startTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.510",
    "endTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.511",
    "caseOne": true,
    "caseTwo": false,
    "caseThree": null
  },
  {
    "objectID": 333222,
    "randomID": 456,
    "desc": "example",
    "startTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.510",
    "endTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.511",
    "caseOne": false,
    "caseTwo": true,
    "caseThree": null
  },
  {
    "objectID": 111111,
    "randomID": 789,
    "desc": "Mo-Fr 60% 20-24",
    "startTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.510",
    "endTime": "2022-03-15T11:31:56.511",
    "caseOne": false,
    "caseTwo": false,
    "caseThree": null
  }
]}
'@
```

```
($contentJson | ConvertFrom-Json).dataCollection |
    Select-Object -Property objectID, randomID, desc |ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
"objectID"      "randomID"      "desc"
"1"     "123"   "The sky is blue"
"333222"        "456"   "example"
"111111"        "789"   "Mo-Fr 60% 20-24"
```

Comment: It works exactly as I imagined, but all the values are written one after the other into the first cell and not per value into a single cell. Is this possible with a simple extension or does this become more complex?

Comment: That is an Excel issue, see e.g.: [How to force Excel to open CSV files with data arranged in columns](https://superuser.com/a/1222081/1085094). You simply try another [`-Delimiter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv#-delimiter)

Comment: It now works the way I wanted it to ($contentJson |ConvertFrom-Json).ttDebugSollZeiten |Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput -NoType -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding Unicode.

I have one last question, which I hope you could answer for me as well. Is there an easy way to exclude keys, for example if I want to exclude "caseOne" in my case?

Thanks a lot Ron

Comment: You better select everything what you *do* want: [`... | Select-Object -Property objectID,randomID,desc,startTime,endTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)

Comment: If I use following command: `($contentJson |ConvertFrom-Json).dataCollection |Select-Object -Property objectID, randomID, desc  |Export-Csv -Path $csvOutput -NoType -Delimiter "t" -Encoding Unicode` I only get the headers in the outcomming csv-file, without any values

Comment: Does the [mcve] in the answer work? Do you get any errors? Which PowerShell version do you use? I recommend to [download and install the latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows).